# Cannot implicitly convert type '.List<AnonymousType#1>' to '.List<WebApplication2.Customer>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

In the following code that returns a list:

```
public List<Customer> GeAllCust()
{
    var results = db.Customers
        .Select(x => new { x.CustName, x.CustEmail, x.CustAddress, x.CustContactNo })
        .ToList()
    return results;
}
```

I get an error reporting that C# can't convert the list:

> Error: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<WebApplication2.Customer>`

Why is that?

Here's a screenshot showing some additional information that Visual Studio provides in a tooltip for the error:

[image]

Is it right way to return some columns instead of whole table....?

```
public object GeAllCust()
{
       var results = db.Customers.Select(x => new { x.CustName, x.CustEmail, x.CustAddress, x.CustContactNo }).ToList();
        return results;
}
```

Comment: Paste your code and exception as a text, not as an image.

Comment: You need to create the `Customer` instance explicitly. Is `db.Customers` already an `IEnumerable<Customer>`? If so, why are you reselecting the 4 properties? Just return `db.Customers.ToList()`. (_Warning:_ Are you attempting to retrieve ***ALL*** customers from your database with no constraints? Hopefully you don't have many populated!)

Comment: Sir....Actually i want to return only 4 coloms from table not the whole table...

Comment: @Hamid, why would you only need to return 4 columns?

Comment: Sir, like SQL query,,, return this this colom.. I want to make the same in Entity framework.. i think if i return whole table it takes extra time to execute the data from table...

Comment: @Hamid, see my updated answer, and unless you are using FileStream, it will not take more time to return more columns unless you have a large amount of rows. If you have a lot of rows, you need to filter down what you return.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you look the code:

```
x => new { ... }
```

This creates a new [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). If you don't need to pull back only a particular set of columns, you can just do the following:

```
return db.Customers.ToList();
```

This assumes that `Customers` is an `IEnumerable<Customer>`, which should match up with what you are trying to return.

**Edit**

You have noted that you only want to return a certain subset of columns. If you want any sort of compiler help when coding this, you need to make a custom class to hold the values:

```
public class CustomerMinInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int? ContactNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your function to the following:

```
public List<CustomerMinInfo> GetAllCust()
{
    var results = db.Customers.Select(x => new CustomerMinInfo()
    {
        Name = x.CustName,
        Email = x.Email,
        Address = x.Address,
        ContactNumber = x.CustContactNo
    })
    .ToList();

    return results;
}
```

This will work, **however**, you will lose all relationship to the database context. This means if you update the returned values, it will not stick it back into the database.

Also, just to repeat my comment, returning more columns (with the exception of byte arrays) does not necessarily mean longer execution time. Returning a lot of rows means more execution time. Your function is returning *every single customer in the database*, which when your system grows, will start to hang your program, even with the reduced amount of columns.

Comment: ...unless `db.Customers` is not an `IEnumerable<Customer>`

Comment: @MarkAvenius, yes, it is just an assumption. I hope with a naming convention like that that it is.

Comment: `x => new CustomerMinInfo()` Was exactly what I needed, Thank-you!

Answer (score 7):

You are selecting to an anonymous type, which is not a `Customer`.

If you want to do (sort of) this, you can write it like this:

```
return db.Customers.Select(x => new Customer { Name = x.CustName, Email = x.CustEmail, Address = x.CustAddress, ContactNo = x.ContactNo }).ToList();
```

This assumes the properties on your `Customer` object are what I called them.

** EDIT ** Per your comment,

If you want to return a subset of the table, you can do one of two things:

1. Return the translated form of `Customer` as I specified above, or:
2. Create a new class for your business layer that only has only those four fields, and change your method to return a `List<ShrunkenCustomer>` (assuming `ShunkenCustomer` is the name that you choose for your new class.)

Comment: good............. Sir may i do like this way as it showin no error..              public object GeAllCust()
        {
           var results = db.Customers.Select(x => new { x.CustName, x.CustEmail, x.CustAddress, x.CustContactNo }).ToList();
            return results;
        }

Comment: The compiler will let you, but you won't be able to access the properties because you can't cast your `object` returned into anything. An anonymous type (`new { ... }`) is only valid within its given scope (in this case, until you leave your method.) You could technically use `dynamic` for this, but I wouldn't recommend it because you would then lose the help of the compiler (compiler errors would go away, but you would get runtime errors instead.)

Comment: I compile the program, it showing nothing.....error....... it showing the list of four coloms                                 GridView1.DataSource = new ConnectionDAL().GeAllCust();
                GridView1.DataBind();

Answer (score 4):

`GetAllCust()` is supposed to return a List of `Customer`, `Select` New will create a list of Anonymous Types, you need to return a list of Customer from your query.
try:

```
var results = db.Customers.Select( new Customer{CustName = x.CustName}).ToList(); //include other fields
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `Customer` is a class you have defined yourself?
The my suggestion would be to do something like the following:

```
var results = db.Customers.Select(x => new Customer(x.Custname, x.CustEmail, x.CustAddress, x.CustContactNo)).ToList();
```

The reason is that you are trying to return a list of `Customer` but the results from your link is an anonymous class containing those four values.
This would of course require that you have a constructor that takes those four values.

Answer (score 1):

Basically whatever u got in var type, loop on that and store it in list<> object then loop and achieve ur target.Here I m posting code for Master details.
List obj = new List();

```
        var orderlist = (from a in db.Order_Master
                         join b in db.UserAccounts on a.User_Id equals b.Id into abc
                         from b in abc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             Order_Id = a.Order_Id,
                             User_Name = b.FirstName,
                             Order_Date = a.Order_Date,
                             Tot_Qty = a.Tot_Qty,
                             Tot_Price = a.Tot_Price,     
                             Order_Status = a.Order_Status,
                             Payment_Mode = a.Payment_Mode,
                             Address_Id = a.Address_Id 

                         });


        List<MasterOrder> ob = new List<MasterOrder>();

        foreach (var item in orderlist)
        {

            MasterOrder clr = new MasterOrder();
            clr.Order_Id = item.Order_Id;
            clr.User_Name = item.User_Name;
            clr.Order_Date = item.Order_Date;
            clr.Tot_Qty = item.Tot_Qty;
            clr.Tot_Price = item.Tot_Price;
            clr.Order_Status = item.Order_Status;       
            clr.Payment_Mode = item.Payment_Mode;
            clr.Address_Id = item.Address_Id;              
            ob.Add(clr);


        }



        using(ecom_storeEntities en=new ecom_storeEntities())
        {
            var Masterlist = en.Order_Master.OrderByDescending(a => a.Order_Id).ToList();


            foreach (var i in ob)
            {
                var Child = en.Order_Child.Where(a => a.Order_Id==i.Order_Id).ToList();
                obj.Add(new OrderMasterChild 
                {
                    Master = i,
                    Childs = Child
                });
            }        


        }
```