# cannot implicitly convert type list anonymous type 1 linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Hi while working on linq  i get this error

> "cannot implicitly convert type list anonymous type 1 linq "

Please go through attached [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YehfX.png)

Comment: Please do not attach images with code. Just post the code here and let everyone know which line throws the error. Also post the full error text

Comment: You are trying to return a grouped anonymous type as a List of PersonInfo. You would need to loop through newCustomerList and create a list of PersonInfo objects to return.

Comment: Possible duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836799/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-listanonymoustype1-to-listwebapplication

Comment: the exception message seems to explain the error for you pretty well. You query returns a list of AnonymousTypes. You need to parse them into `List<PersonInfo>`, which is the type returned by your method.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17836923/5558781

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your linq query, you are defining a new type that cannot be converted to a PersonInfo object.  To fix this, you need to define the PersonInfo object in the select.  That way your return statement is the same as your object.

```
List<PersonInfo> newCustomerList = userList.GroupBy(u=>u.ID)
                                   .Select(group=> new PersonInfo() {  }).ToList();
```

Inside the new PersonInfo, you would need to set the values that define a PersonInfo type.